# How to link two networks together through a windows 10 laptop

Tags: windows, networking, subnet

I have two networks with subnets 10.0.0.0/24 and 192.168.1.0/24 and I want to link them together so 192.168.1.2 can ping 10.0.0.2 without going through a proxy

I do not have access to either router and I cannot connect the routers or bring in another one. my laptop has to act as the router.

Can I do this with as little configuration as possible?

Comment: offtopic. You seek for NAT and windows as a router

Comment: You want to have routing between two networks ... but without a routing device?

Comment: Yes, this is called routing. If you don't want to employ routing, this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Routers route between subnets.

First, you need two interfaces/NICs, one connected to each subnet. For Windows 10 to enable routing you need to edit the registry. In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters` you change the value for `IPEnableRouter` to `0001`. If that value is missing create a `REG_DWORD` with that name. Reboot.

In each subnet, point a specific route to the other subnet to the laptop interface, e.g. with the laptop using 10.0.0.99 and 192.168.1.99 and Windows machines:

```
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.99 -p
```

or

```
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255. 10.0.0.99 -p
```

The `-p` makes that route entry survive a system restart.

If you need Internet access from the subnet not connecting to your WAN router, you need to tell that WAN router about the remote subnet as well (same route as above) and use the laptop interface on the remote subnet as default gateway.